# How can I setup a persistence Python virtual environment in a Dockerfile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, containers, python-venv

I'm building Python 3.7.4 (It's a hard requirement for other software) on a base Ubuntu 20.04 image using a Dockerfile.  I'm following [this guide](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2017/06/30/building-python-ubuntu-wsl-debian/).

Everything works fine if I run the image and follow the guide, but I want to setup my virtual environment in the Dockerfile and have the pip requirements persistent when running the image.

Here's the relevant part of my Dockerfile:

```
...
RUN echo =============== Building and Install Python =============== \
    && cd /tmp \
    && wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/Python-3.7.4.tgz \
    && tar xvf ./Python-3.7.4.tgz \
    && cd Python-3.7.4 \
    && ./configure --enable-optimizations --with-ensurepip=install \
    && make -j 8 \
    && sudo make install

ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/opt/python-3.7.4
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV:$PATH"
COPY  "./hourequirements.txt" /usr/local/
RUN echo =============== Setting up Python Virtual Environment =============== \
    && python3 -m venv $VIRTUAL_ENV \
    && source $VIRTUAL_ENV/bin/activate \
    && pip install --upgrade pip \
    && pip install --no-input -r /usr/local/hourequirements.txt
...
```

The Dockerfile builds without errors, but when I run the image the environment doesn't exist and python 3.7.4 doesn't show any of the installed requirements.

How can I install Python modules in the virtual environment using PIP in the Dockerfile and have them persist when the docker image runs?

Comment: how about move `activate` commands from `RUN` to `CMD/EntryPoint`?

Comment: The Docker container itself is isolated from the host system (and it already has its own Python installation); do you actually need a virtual environment in addition to that?

Comment: @DavidMaze yeah not 100% sure if I need a virtual environment in the container, but I know that Ubuntu 20.04 comes with Py 3.8 and I'm containerising software that has a hard dependency on Py 3.7.4.  This is less about isolating Py inside the container and more about having py 3.8 and py 3.7 installed inside the container.

Comment: 'having py 3.8 and py 3.7' one docker should only have one version, in common cases.

Answer (score 0):

Usual find answer just after post.

I changed:

```
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV:$PATH"
```

to:

```
ENV PATH="$VIRTUAL_ENV/bin:$PATH"
```

in Dockerfile and started working correctly.